# Save JS output with PHP

Tags: php, javascript, output

i want to save output/result of JavaScript code. For example:

```
<script>document.write(navigator.appVersion)</script>
```

For PHP i have no problem:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; 
$file = "log.txt"; 
$open = fopen($file, "a+");
```

Then write:

```
fwrite($open, "<b>IP Address:</b> " .$ip . "<br/>");
```

Now i'd like to write result of JavaScript with same method.

Of course this will not work:

```
fwrite($open, "<script>document.write(navigator.appVersion)</script>");
```

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: You can't do it like that, javascript runs on the client side. You will have to first get the data and send it back to the server, or you can use the user agent

Comment: use "echo" function to write to the page

Comment: Have you tried writing the result using AJAX? You'd send `navigator.appVerison` to a PHP file using AJAX.

Comment: If you want to do this all server side then you'll need some sort of headless browser to render the javaScript. There are lots available for linux, a quick google just pointed me towards this: http://phantomjs.org/

Answer (score 2):

If you need to get information about the user's browser, use a PHP function. You can't get the Javascript output from PHP unless you send it back using Ajax.

To get the browser information using PHP, use [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)